# How to change correctly postgresql 'datestyle' parameter in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, postgresql-10

How to change correctly postgresql `'datestyle'` parameter in docker-compose.yml?
In container from image in  /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf the defulat is `datestyle = 'iso, mdy'`, i want to change it to `datestyle = 'iso, dmy'`.

I've trying next:
in docker-compose.yaml:

```
environment:
- PGDATESTYLE='iso, dmy'
```

after this get an error while starting container

*2023-06-15 07:54:26.859 GMT [51] FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "DateStyle": "'iso, dmy'"
2023-06-15 07:54:26.859 GMT [51] DETAIL:  Unrecognized key word: "'iso".*

then i try in docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  pg_base:
    command: postgres -c 'datestyle="iso, dmy"'
```

and get error

*2023-06-15 07:56:39.783 GMT [1] FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "DateStyle": ""iso, dmy""
2023-06-15 07:56:39.783 GMT [1] DETAIL:  Unrecognized key word: "iso, dmy".*